# Two bot commands dependent on each other

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot for a very specific need. That is picking team captains from a voice chat. My current command looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'captains',
    guildOnly: true,
    execute(message) {
       var voiceUsers = message.member.voiceChannel.members;
       //pick 2 random users
      },
};
```

It does the job, but I want to exclude repeating the same user when other didn't have a turn yet. So I want to create a lobby that will track the users picked and then Captains command will exclude them from random picking.
So create-lobby command:

```
    name: 'create-lobby',
    description: 'Create a lobby',
    execute(message) {
       var pickedUsers = new Map();
       //something goes here?        
    },
};
```

My question is how do I make Captains command interact with var from create-lobby? To check if the lobby was created even and then add picked users to the list. I couldn't find this with a basic google search, tho it may be due to wrong wording as I am new to javascript, if so I apologize and will delete this question when I know what to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your solution is in storing the lobby somewhere else, like a JSON (very simple and it don't scale very well but since your bot seems very specific it can help) OR you can start working on a database (not so simple but it scales very well)

[This can help you with the JSON method](https://anidiots.guide/coding-guides/json-based-points-system)

[This can help you with the database method](https://anidiots.guide/coding-guides/sqlite-based-points-system)

Comment: thank you so much! i will check out both methods cause this bot is more for me to learn than to use for games with friends. So thank you for including both :)